# Set all <canvas>'s in the html document to the document's width and height?

Tags: javascript

Without the use of jquery (ie only using old javascript), how can I set all canvas's in the html document to the document's width and height?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: Both Chief's and Naelio's answers are technically **incorrect**.

---

**Naelio:**
Changing the canvas's **style** will change the canvas's **CLIENT WIDTH** and **CLIENT HEIGHT** not the **actual** width and height so the content of the canvas will end up being scaled / stretched.
Example of this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/AnLCw/1/ (note how the black 50x50 square is stretched using the style approach)

---

**Chief17**:
You can't specify the width and height of a canvas in percentages.  Example of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sg7cb/2/  (note that no canvas shows up when width and height are percentages)

---

So here is the **actual solution**:

You need to set the canvas's style to be: width: 100% and height: 100%

```
canvas.style.width = "100%"
canvas.style.height = "100%"
```

and then do:

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/acYdc/1/  (Notice how the black square draws correctly and the canvas fills the area.)

Another solution is just to set

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

but the canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth approach is more flexible.

Comment: Nice answer - and thanks for explaining where mine could be improved :)

Comment: np.  Hope you don't mind that I called it out by name but I don't know of another way to refer to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfeV/

You will need to give the document a height so the canvas knows how big to expand to, otherwise it will expand to whatever height the document gains by the internal height of its child elements.

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');

for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {

    canvases[i].style.width = '100%';
    canvases[i].style.height = '100%';
    canvases[i].width = canvases[i].clientWidth;
    canvases[i].height = canvases[i].clientHeight;

}
```